# OpenvSwitch PLVAN support

Tags: openvswitch

I have looked up the supported feature of OpenvSwitch on the official website. However, I couldn't find any support for PVLAN.
I wonder if OVS supports Private VLAN (PVLAN) which is composed of primary (promiscuous) and secondary VLAN (isolated, Community)?

Comment: anyone?!!!!!!!!!